# I get image field upload errors with a custom node_add() form

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I use module as a link [enter link description here](https://github.com/Itangalo/Node-creation-block--Drupal-7-)

an it work correct but if the node form has file upload this affect error :

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'node_form' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 800 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\includes\form.inc). Notice: Undefined index: #node in comment_form_node_form_alter() (line 1194 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\comment\comment.module). Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in comment_form_node_form_alter() (line 1211 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\comment\comment.module). Notice: Undefined index: #node in location_node_form_node_form_alter() (line 14 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\sites\all\modules\location\location_node.module). Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in location_node_form_node_form_alter() (line 15 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\sites\all\modules\location\location_node.module). Notice: Undefined index: #node in menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 629 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\menu\menu.module). Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 629 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\menu\menu.module). Notice: Undefined index: #node in menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 630 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\menu\menu.module). Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 630 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\menu\menu.module). Notice: Undefined index: #node in translation_form_node_form_alter() (line 135 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\translation\translation.module). Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in translation_form_node_form_alter() (line 135 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\translation\translation.module). Notice: Undefined index: field_im in file_ajax_upload() (line 271 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\file\file.module). Notice: Undefined index: #suffix in file_ajax_upload() (line 280 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\file\file.module).

how i solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by use

```
function yourmodule_menu_alter(&$items) {$items['system/ajax']['file path'] =drupal_get_path('module', 'node');$items['system/ajax']['file'] = 'node.pages.inc';}
```